# Symfony 3.0 netbeans configuration

Tags: symfony, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm trying to use symfony with netbeans I have created manually a project in command line. I have imported the project to netbeans and in options tools /frameworks I've added installer the 'symfony' file and then I went to properties of my project and went to frameworks - symfony2 and wanted to save it as enabled but it will not let me because "App directory must be underneath Source Files."

My file tree looks like this:

```
Symfony projects
    -symfony
    Test123
          app
          bin
          nbproject
          src
          tests
          var
          vendor
          web
```

Answer (score 3):

Even if this thread is a bit old, I will post an answer because I stumbled upon the same problem just today.

If you have problems with Netbeans recognizing your Symfony project, go to your project properties (File > Project Properties) and then klick on ‘Sources‘. Define your project root as source folder, i.e. in your case ‘Test123’, then Netbeans should automatically detect the usage of the symfony framework. If it does not, you can now select ‘app’ as your App Directory since it is now ‘underneath the Source Files’.

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 8.2 with Symfony 3.1, using your solution and I get this working :).

Answer (score 0):

when you want to import existing project :

Files->new project->PHP->php application with existing source.

and you choose the folder that contain app of your symfony(Test123 in your case)